# Binning of continuous variables in sklearn ensemble and trees

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree, ensemble-learning

Can anyone tell me how ensembles (like Random Forest, Gradient Boosting, Adaboost) and trees (like Decision Trees) in sklearn (Python) take care of continuous variables ? Are they treated as each individual value when building the trees ? Or are they automatically binned ? If they are binned - what is the logic followed. If they are not binned, I am sure I am missing something. There should be some intelligent binning available (in built?) which will bin the variable values in bins according to class distribution (at least in case of binary classification)

In depth: When I load my arff (millions of rows and few hundred features in a highly skewed data set), in weka, and scroll through the variables/target(binary) plots, I can see that many of them have strong bins (areas where the target is positive). Are these bins i.e >=x <=y automatically picked up by the above models mentioned in sklearn ? See attached picture (if you can see it there are very thin red lines of 6 bars in a variable/target plot)

Will be really grateful for any insight on this

Regards

[image]

Comment: every node of every tree is a bin in itself defined be the upstream splitting rules. There are rarely any perfect binning procedures, but the average ensemble of many low-correlated tree models perform well can even become an almost smooth function estimator. If a continuous variable has values 1:5(1 to 5) the possible splits are 1;2:5, 1:2;3:5, 1:3;4:5 and 1:4;5. It is quite fast to try hundred or thousands of possible break points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the default settings (non-random splits), every time a decision or regression tree is grown by splitting a dataset, the part of the dataset under consideration is sorted by the values of each of the features under consideration in turn (in a random forest or ExtraTrees forest, features may be randomly selected each time). Then the mean of every adjacent pair `f[i], f[j]` of feature values is considered as a candidate split, except if the pair is less than 1e-7 apart (an arbitrary constant currently hardwired in the code). The best split, according to the Gini/entropy/other split criterion is used to split the dataset into those points with `f < (f[i] + f[j]) / 2` and those with higher value for `f`.

I.o.w., no explicit binning is performed.

(I'm not actually much of a decision tree expert, but I did work on the scikit-learn implementation, in particular I optimized the splitting code by writing a faster sorting algorithm for it.)

Comment: Larsmans - thats great, st from the horses mouth. Thanks. I wonder why adjacent pair of features. E.g say if house_sqft, house_pincode, house_hasdeck are the selected features for a single tree deciding house_highvalue (yes or no). If I got it right - first the data set is split on house_sqft <> (sum(house_sqft) + sum(house_pincode)/2 and gini/entropy is calculated. Then the data set is split on house_sqft <> (sum(house_sqft) + sum(house_hasdeck)/2 and so on.... ? But that will surely call for normalization across features (not generally used) and loose information too. Surely I must be wrong

Comment: @Run2: I mean *adjacent samples after sorting*. So you sort the houses on `sqft`, then compare all n-1 pairs `sqft[i], sqft[i+1]` where *i* indexes the sorted list of houses. (It's really just computing all splits, maybe I went into too much algorithmic detail. The decision tree algo in scikit-learn is the one you find in textbooks such as ISLR.)

Comment: thanks, I understand. I definitely think there is a scope for improvement here. Would love to work on it and implement it.  I did some research on sub group discovery and it may be a good add on/ extra feature to this splitting logic. Please advice if you have some pointers on how to tread that way.

Comment: @Run2 Sign up on the mailing list and post a message there. It's listed somewhere on http://scikit-learn.org.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly what scikit-learn does, but I suspect that there is no binning and that it simply uses continuous values as they are. In the simplest form of a decision tree, the rules you test are simply x_j >= x_ij for every variable and for every observed realization of that variable.

The [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html) (see 1.8.7 Mathematical Formulation) suggests that they use this simple approach. Just test every (or maybe some subset) possible threshold for every variable.

Comment: When you have millions of rows with values that are close to each other (in each feature), yet different from each other, that kind of tree building will not work nicely. If you see the above figure - there are strong bins and there might be weak beans (you cannot see red as it is probably too thin) in each feature. If we can get the strong bins for each feature, and create rules by combining them, that may give much better classification compared to checking individual values. Specially in skewed data, where there are lots of 0 values in the bins too. There must be something out there.

Comment: Yea, but in that case you should probably do it on your own. If I were designing a general-use decision tree implementation, I would feel very uncomfortable doing that under-the-hood. That kind of feature transformation takes domain and data knowledge. Of course, keep in mind that I don't actually know the sk-learn implementation, I'm just going off their documentation.

Comment: Hmm - ok - thanks Roger. I will wait and see if any one else gives any other advice. How is WEKA binning it ? If I hover over the bars in WEKA then I can see it has done some kind of binning for each feature.